# setting global envrionment variables in multiple docker compose files

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, yaml

I have the following setup:

There are multiple services running on my server, all hosted via docker compose. I register them all to a traefik reverse proxy via docker labels.

The services are "hosted" in different docker compose files so I don't have to `down` and `up` the whole stack whenever I make changes to one service.

Think of the following structure

```
├── service-a
│   ├── docker-compose.yml
│   └── additional-stuff...
└── service-b
    ├── docker-compose.yml
    └── additional-stuff...
```

Every directory like this is a separate git repository that contains everything it needs to run, including config files.

Now I register all the containers to traefik via labels like this (cyberchef is just an example):

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  cyber-chef:
    image: mpepping/cyberchef:latest
    restart: always
    networks:
      - frontend
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.cyberchef-rtr.rule=Host(`cyberchef.example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.cyberchef-rtr.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.cyberchef-rtr.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.cyberchef-rtr.middlewares=chain-no-auth@file"
      - "traefik.http.routers.cyberchef-rtr.service=cyberchef-svc"
      - "traefik.http.services.cyberchef-svc.loadbalancer.server.port=8000"

networks:
  frontend:
    external: true
```

Now what I want to do is basically have a central config/.env file that contains stuff most of the services share. Things like setting the timezone or having a `$DOMAIN` env var so I can do `` - "traefik.http.routers.cyberchef-rtr.rule=Host(`cyberchef.${DOMAIN}`)" ``. Maybe using a submodule?

Using a .env file is not possible since I would need to manually copy paste that between repos because submodules need a dedicated directory. Using `- env_file` works for stuff like timezones, but doesn't let me use the labes syntax above, because the env vars are only passed to the container and aren't usable in the docker-compose.yml itself.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You shouldn't usually need to `docker-compose down`, and `docker-compose up -d` will recreate (only) containers that have changed since you last run it.  Does it simplify things to combine the application into a single Compose file?

Comment: I mean it would simplify it, but also make it less portable and less versatile. One of the things I like about this setup, for example, is being able to up and down my foundry server that doesn't need to run all the time. It's more modular and I have granular control over what's currently running.